# Как вместо переменной вставить число

Tags: vbscript

вопрос. Во фразе "Вау, твоё число - х", вместо "х" мне необходимо, чтобы отображалось то значение, которое введёт пользователь. Как это сделать?

Код:

```
x = inputbox("Введите число от 1 до 13:")

if (x >= 14) then

msgbox "ОТ 1 ДО 13!"

elseif (x < 1) then

msgbox "ОТ 1 ДО 13!"

else

msgbox "Вау, твоё число - x"

end if
```

Comment: вынести ``x`` за кавычки, чтобы он был переменной, а не частью строки

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать оператор `&` или `+` для объединения значений.
Также, код можно сделать более читабельным и простым за счет объединения условий - здесь, в частности, с помощью логического оператора `OR`.

```
x = inputbox("Введите число от 1 до 13:")

if (x < 1) or (x > 13) then
    msgbox "ОТ 1 ДО 13!"
else
    msgbox "Вау, твоё число - " & x
end if
```